# How to know which class belongs to a variable in php?

Tags: php, laravel

how do I know what kind of class is a variable in php:

```
 if($var == \Collection)
   echo "congratulations";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

```
if($var instanceof \Collection) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_class($object)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

> Returns the name of the class of an object

or use [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) in `if`:

```
if ($object instanceof Collection) {
    ...
}
```